# Simple way of converting list from character to numeric in R?

Tags: arrays, r, dataframe

I have looking into other threads on this problem and could not find an easy solution. I have imported data from Excel tables, and joined them in lists which generally look like this:

```
> Hemo
[[1]]
V1 V2 V3 V4  V5  V6  V7
1 0d 3d 6d 9d 12d 15d 18d
2 10 40 20 60  50  30  40
3 20 30 30 30  30  30  30
4 20 20 30 20  40  20  50

[[2]]
V1 V2 V3 V4  V5  V6  V7
1 0d 3d 6d 9d 12d 15d 18d
2  0 10 10  0   0   0   0
3  0 10 20 20  20   0   0
4  0  0 10 20  20   0   0
```

However I'd like them to look like this (which is an array):

```
, , 1

0d 3d 6d 9d 12d 15d 18d
V2 10 40 20 60  50  30  40
V3 20 30 30 30  30  30  30
V4 20 20 30 20  40  20  50

, , 2

0d 3d 6d 9d 12d 15d 18d
V2  0 10 10  0   0   0   0
V3  0 10 20 20  20   0   0
V4  0  0 10 20  20   0   0
```

In the first case all elements are characters and I am not being able to coerse them to numbers. Ultimately I'd like to convert the first list into the second array where the first imported line figures as the column names. There must be some package enabling this? Please let us find a simple workaround as I am a newbie. Thanks

Comment: did you use the lapply function ???`lapply(Hemo, as.numeric)`

Comment: It's not too hard to solve, but it'd be better to import it in the right format from the beginning. How do your read the excel sheets ? There's probably a heard or colnames parameter that you can set to TRUE, then the data may be recognized as numbers automatically and you won't need to do that

Comment: and it would be more something like `lapply(Hemo,function(m){names(m)<- m[1,];m <- as.numeric(m[2:nrow(m),])})`

Comment: Yeah, I am importing all again specifying header then. Still I thought converting should be easier, but there is some issue there with factors interpretation in the object which is beyond me now.

Comment: BTW @R.B as.numeric() returns me some other numbers which are some attribute, I have tried many different ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as though you imported the data from excel, but the columnnames were interpreted as data. You didn't specify which function you used to do the importing, but with most of them you can specify that the first row of data are columnnames.

```
library(readxl)
data <- read_excel(filename, col_names = TRUE)
```

When you import your data properly, it won't confuse the actual data, and should automatically read it as numerics. This way you won't have to convert it yourself.